# PHP clone method

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling to figure out how to use `$clone` method. I did it the easy way I guess but my mentor told me to look into `$clone` method. But I have no success in implementing it so I came for a bit of a help.

https://jsfiddle.net/Krichukz/6uy0f3xa/5/

Expected results when button <kbd>cloned</kbd> is pressed.
First 2 fields before clone:

- `myinputs[0][first_name]`
- `myinputs[0][last_name]`

After <kbd>cloned</kbd> button pushed, four fields:

- `myinputs[0][first_name]`
- `myinputs[0][last_name]`
- `myinputs[1][first_name]`
- `myinputs[1][last_name]`

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
        var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
        var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
        var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="myinputs[][first_name]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" "/></a><input type="text" name="myinputs[][last_name]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" /></a></div> ';
       
        var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
        $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
            if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
                x++; //Increment field counter
                $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field
            }
        });
        $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
            x--; //Decrement field counter
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="html_pdf.php">
    <div class="field_wrapper">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="myinputs[0][first_name]">
            <input type="text" name="myinputs[0][last_name]"><br>

            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add-icon.png" alt="+ Add"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type='submit' value='submit' name="submit" id='submit'>
</form>
```

I guess it needs to be in an array so I can push those values into the database.

Comment: There are so many issues with the code you are providing. Is like the HTML does not correspond to the javascript code. This is also not a PHP question. I suggest  providing the example as a working snippet

Comment: @Pablo added jsfiddle with working example, i'm trying to do that with $clone function, so i can push the data with php foreach into database. At the moment when im trying to display the data with foreach it does come out wrong.

Comment: `<table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php
            foreach($_POST['myinputs'] as $input) :
            ?>
            <td><?php echo  $input['first_name']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $input['last_name']  ?></td>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </table>
</div>`

Cause when i call this out it comes out as https://i.imgur.com/ir9Sgwo.png.

Comment: take a look at my answer. The POST array won't be formatted the way you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not include a field name like `myinputs[][first_name]` it has to be either `myinputs[1][first_name]` or `myinputs[first_name][]`. If using the empty square brackets they should always be at the end of the name.

Below is the updated example that included the updated names like `myinputs[first_name][]`. To see how the POST is formatted in the PHP backend use `print_r($_POST)`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
        var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
        var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
        var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="myinputs[first_name][]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" "/></a><input type="text" name="myinputs[last_name][]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" /></a></div> ';
       
        var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
        $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
            if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
                x++; //Increment field counter
                $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field
            }
        });
        $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
            x--; //Decrement field counter
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="https://requestbin.fullcontact.com/u1ylwbu1">
    <div class="field_wrapper">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="myinputs[first_name][]">
            <input type="text" name="myinputs[last_name][]"><br>

            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add-icon.png" alt="+ Add"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type='submit' value='submit' name="submit" id='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: what would be the correct way to push the values in to database? @Pablo Thanks for the help, gonna mark it as an answer as soon as i'm able to figure print thing out :)